# DSE Graph - How to see the underlying Cassandra queries from Gremlin queries?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

If I execute a gremlin query in the `gremlin-console`, is there a way to see the Cassandra queries DSE Graph generates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSE Graph provides an extended set of attributes to the results of TinkerPop's [profile() step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#profile-step) - here is an example of the output:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('recipe','name','spaghetti').profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
DsegGraphStep([~label.=(recipe), name.=(spaghet...                     1           1          97.087    81.00
  query-optimizer                                                                             22.802
    \_condition=(((label = recipe) & (true)) & name = spaghetti)
  query-setup                                                                                  1.134
    \_isFitted=true
    \_isSorted=false
    \_isScan=false
  index-query                                                                                 19.838
    \_indexType=Secondary
    \_usesCache=false
    \_statement=SELECT "community_id", "member_id" FROM "junk"."recipe_p" WHERE "name" = ? LIMIT ?; with para
                ms (java.lang.String) spaghetti, (java.lang.Integer) 50000
    \_options=Options{consistency=Optional[ONE], serialConsistency=Optional.empty, fallbackConsistency=Option
              al.empty, pagingState=null, pageSize=-1, user=Optional.empty, waitForSchemaAgreement=true, asyn
              c=true}
DsegPropertyLoadStep                                                   1           1          22.772    19.00
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -         119.860        -
```

Comment: When I use `profile()`, it only provides the steps of the query plan but not the Cassandra queries. In your example, I suppose it provided that Cassandra snippet only because the query hit a secondary index? If it doesn't require the secondary index hit, then it nothing related to Cassandra would show for me. Is it true what I said?

Comment: Display of the CQL was added after DSE to 5.0.10 and 5.1.2 I believe - it wasn't available prior to that. Perhaps you need to upgrade to have this feature?

Comment: Thanks. I see it now. Was using 5.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Stephen is correct.  This feature was added in 5.1.2.  You'll see the JIRA (DSP-13293) in the release notes for 5.1.2.  What version are you using?

Comment: Thanks. I see it now. Was using 5.1.1.